# Is it possible to get the number of users messaged by the send dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-ui

I'm wondering if its possible to retrieve the number of people/friends messaged by a user when they use the 'send dialog' to send specific friends a messages (just a number is ok). I've been looking through the documentation for the send dialog but it doesn't seem to have any information regarding this.(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/).

An alternative I can think of at this stage would be to use the graph API, but then I'd need to know the messageID of the message the user just sent.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can get the count 
first :you should know when user sent a message Check the link below
here is a sample for you
to test it :
http://www.fbrell.com/saved/d002a25a351e6b01b0526b2606b48750

```
 <script>
    FB.ui({
              method: 'send',
              name: 'People Argue Just to Win',
              link: 'http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html',
              },
      function(response) {
        if (response) {
          alert('message sent.');
        } else {
          alert('not sent');
        }
      }
    );

    </script>
```

second:use jQuery & via jquery load ($().load('page.php');
you can save who sent message with uid & of course you can get count every time you want